# Unable to verify assembly data; you must provide an authorization key when loading this assembly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm testing the InteractiveConsole example in Unity. I did some configurations as described in [the official tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas).
After some setups I got on step *7: Run our example code*.

However, I'm receiving the following errors:

> Unable to verify assembly data; you must provide an authorization key
>   when loading this assembly.
>   UnityEngine.Security:LoadAndVerifyAssembly(Byte[])
>   c__Iterator1:MoveNext() (at
>   Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:326)
>
> Could not securely load assembly from
>   https://integrated-plugin-canvas-rsrc.fbsbx.com/rsrc/unity/lib/sdk_4.0/CanvasFacebook.dll
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object) FbDebug:Error(String)
>   c__Iterator1:MoveNext() (at
>   Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:329)

Not sure what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of the Unity Editor are you on?

Comment: I'm using 4.6 pro (BETA)
But the problem remains in 4.3.4.

Comment: Unity recently updated `Security:LoadAndVerifyAssembly` to take an authorization key in Unity Editor 4.5.  We are working to have that support on Facebook's end.  For now the current version is only supported for Unity Editor <4.5

Comment: For now as a workaround if you want to stay with Unity Editor 4.5+, open `FB.cs` and look for `var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerify Assembly(www.bytes);`

change that to:
`var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes, "o+uJXoVE53pt2yC+6MNtM+S1eQ12KoaJUWOveWIZ9Q3BWQTqhcWA9mllY6HjVXSLY5E0uWEgAWGalwSf4z8c3XIfIInxSjh33N8IYCyMsrkctcj4LhPIl+EcKDgY4L2xKFqqiEi5k7z6LU3M4+RY+7LsgGL7m7Io+8F/LxoOhnoWVGCQ1uXgQ+8G4emvplGRQy7usgruhbHvMsWtd9GXhJV29gFQa3h88R5obXgxNKGXQea0Ex8dQdRS41TS7+fywh6RFsoq9sFxi+dePoW8bGBP+NxKpCxzEIk8UVRD8fZsE/Zl2FzGyIGjn5QXJuPrS+rYhLLbqfLz07Inf7LNCg==");`

Comment: Can you post updated data for the 5.0.3 release?

Comment: Here's the newest key:
`B8GvecdX0rQ47kzhCEwlrRzYKA8LKeiZxy1HI3HfnhdgUATvBwQQViji8ot44dADM55QuHk5+hwrLsoau32IDmRDQTclMSsTsIywGRo/nE5vbmRMMIECYXBFhliz+kvK0RWZ57XPxw0s7YhGnNLav0EE2QH/m+9ajlLOY+2ckxSoSEHLpotllyZLktRK+oFiDPvmzXLDUMOnwK9RFRSh2VBmoyWTZx8BYqWjqug3kAljJk/XwTYZT9Ie+HvzLO5DBSqMNYbEX03WaNfpaq9GKBF/Oz37AHelf1Es36amP1v2Aut3nmIk2xxN6zwzBXyEyw90vJ/O8suikU+8kDDbZA==`

Comment: I'm getting:

FormatException: Invalid character found.
System.Convert.FromBase64String (System.String s) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Convert.cs:146)
UnityEngine.Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly (System.Byte[] assemblyData, System.String authorizationKey) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/aeedb04a1292f85a/Runtime/Export/Security.cs:66)
FB+RemoteFacebookLoader+<LoadFacebookClass>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:358)

:|

Comment: Ok, it seems that some utf symbols copy themselves when you copy the whole thing from SO. Copy line by line.

Comment: Hi @Brain Jew could you please link to / comment how you generated that key if you have a moment? Thanks.

Comment: This is the exact problem I was getting, adding the line reference on my code just for search reference,

var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes);

Adding the answer below like RemeR suggested solved it for me.

Answer (score 30):

Instead of change the call to LoadAndVerifyAssembly as @BrianJew suggests, you simply can change the line 381 of FB.cs, where it says

```
#if UNITY_4_5
```

you should put

```
#if UNITY_4_5 || UNITY_4_6
```

Or the appropiate flag for your Unity's version. In that block the key is obtained from this URL https://integrated-plugin-canvas-rsrc.fbsbx.com/rsrc/unity/key/sdk_5.1/AuthToken.unityhash

Comment: It works. In Facebook Unity SDK 6.0, it's on line 411.

Comment: You will need to add Unity_5_1 for 5.1

Comment: @mikeysee Thank you. This helped me speed up the process.

Comment: It's probably better just adding UNITY_EDITOR

Comment: Worked!
They should add al version by default.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple fix:

Change line 411 of `FB.cs` to:

```
#if UNITY_4_5 || UNITY_EDITOR
```

This has been tested in version `5.2.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing for unity 5.1, just add `|| UNITY_5_1` to corresponding line in FB.cs