# LoadAndVerifyAssembly failure, SDK 5.0.3

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Loading the Facebook SDK in recent versions of Unity causes a failure at line 326 in FB.cs. The error message appears when pressing play in the editor, and reads "Unable to verify assembly data; you must provide an authorization key when loading this assembly."

I believe this is the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815128/unable-to-verify-assembly-data-you-must-provide-an-authorization-key-when-loadi), but no one answered my comment asking for an updated authorization key. If it's the same issue, can this problem please be fixed, and in the meantime post workaround keys for 5.0.3 and 5.0.4 SDKs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the newest workaround key:
`B8GvecdX0rQ47kzhCEwlrRzYKA8LKeiZxy1HI3HfnhdgUATvBwQQViji8ot44dADM55QuHk5+hwrLsoau32IDmRDQTclMSsTsIywGRo/nE5vbmRMMIECYXBFhliz+kvK0RWZ57XPxw0s7YhGnNLav0EE2QH/m+9ajlLOY+2ckxSoSEHLpotllyZLktRK+oFiDPvmzXLDUMOnwK9RFRSh2VBmoyWTZx8BYqWjqug3kAljJk/XwTYZT9Ie+HvzLO5DBSqMNYbEX03WaNfpaq9GKBF/Oz37AHelf1Es36amP1v2Aut3nmIk2xxN6zwzBXyEyw90vJ/O8suikU+8kDDbZA==`

Comment: Where are you getting these from? I need one for 4.3.6 if you've got one handy ;)

Comment: Hi, 4.3.6 doesn't support Unity 4.5+.  Please upgrade to 5.1