# So does the facebook sdk not work for unity 4.5?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

From previous questions asked on this topic([LoadAndVerifyAssembly failure, SDK 5.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650435/loadandverifyassembly-failure-sdk-5-0-3/22671652#22671652?newreg=0a40e411106a4ab7a129a3e17941d945)) it looks like some "workaround" keys are needed to make it work. What are workaround keys? Where to get them from? Do they get expired with time?

Comment: Did I just get a negative vote for a perfectly valid question? What the...

Answer (score 0):

Alright dont answer my question anyone. Somehow after grinding for 2 days I realized that the solution was to download the facebook sdk from the facebook website and not the unity asset store. Unity asset store does not have the latest version with this fix. I don't know why they'd do this to us. Anyway I hope this helps anyone else stuck out there!