# FB.Login Facebook Unity SDK 5.1 + Unity 4.6 beta9 NullReferenceException

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

(In Unity Editor)
After calling FB.Login and being presented with the User Access Token popup if I login or Cancel and the popup goes away I will be hit with an endless barrage of NullReferenceExceptions:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEngine.GUI.CallWindowDelegate (UnityEngine.WindowFunction func, Int32 id, UnityEngine.GUISkin _skin, Int32 forceRect, Single width, Single height, UnityEngine.GUIStyle style)

There is no further callstack.

Is this a known problem with Unity beta or is it something I can avoid?

Comment: Might be something to do with the Unity you are running, since I run FB Unity SDK 5.1 & Unity 4.3 and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I am using Unity 4.6.09b right now and I am experimenting the same issue. 
The only thing that helped was this [Unable to verify assembly data; you must provide an authorization key when loading this assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815128/unable-to-verify-assembly-data-you-must-provide-an-authorization-key-when-loadi) but it was to fix another issue.

Comment: Yeah - I found the issue went away after a while then came back some time later. I sidestepped the issue by creating an auto-login step in the Facebook code so the access token window never showed up.

Comment: @hey-ben can you answer your solution and mark it as accepted? How did you create an auto-login step?